# Are there any MIDI keyboard controllers with light up keys that can be controlled via MIDI?

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard

I am looking for MIDI keyboard controllers with light up keys.

I know that there are several like this made for learning (but I don't need key lights for learning purposes) where in most of the cases, the user is not in control of turning the LEDs on/off individually e.g. via a MIDI message.

So far I found the LUMI Keys by Roli, but it seems lights would not react to MIDI input. The [manual](https://playlumi.com/assets/manual.pdf) at page 24 seems to suggest that, however there is not trace of documentation about MIDI messages -_-

Any LUMI owner that can disprove that?

Another one I found is the QuNexus by Keith McMillen, which according to the [manual](https://files.keithmcmillen.com/downloads/qunexus/QuNexus_FullManual_1.0.pdf), section 2.6, it offers control of the lights via MIDI note messages. I do not particularly love a keyboard with rubber pads, but maybe it's worth a try...

Any other controllers?

The preferred octave range would be 2-3.5 octaves, and a low price tag ;)

Comment: Most of the Yamahas I've ever used, if they have lights the lights respond just the same to incoming Midi on Ch1 as they do to pressed keys. [It's not something I've ever seriously investigated… as I have no use for it;)

Comment: My personal view is that lighting up keys will not particularly help you learn to play. There are many other tried and tested methods that work more effectively.

Comment: @Tim I don't need light up keys for learning :D I need those to develop custom sequencing applications